# Removing the key of associative array not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like the following.

```
array(1) {
  ["ftr_file_uploads"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(13) "Hydrangeas.jpg"
      }
      ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }   
    }  
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(13) "w.jpg"
      }
       ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }  
    }
  }
}
```

I need to change the array structure to the following format.

```
array(1) {
  ["ftr_file_uploads"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Hydrangeas.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "w.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
      array(2) {
       [0]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
      [1]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the following.

```
foreach($_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'] as $keyval1=>$value1) {
    $_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'][] = $_FILES[$keyval1];
    unset($_FILES[$keyval1]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mehdi Sorry,I forgot to paste what i have done

Comment: Can you make a simple data sample? so that it is easily readable, don't forget the expected result too.

Comment: Yes..I will do now

Comment: Manipulating an array your'e currently iterating over *can* cause unexpected behaviour. Your'e literally sawing off the Tree-Branch your'e sitting on.

Comment: @Mehdi Modified the array to simple form

Comment: @FabianSchöner I have simplified the array

Comment: @Mehdi I have modified the code.The name parameter values was different previously

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
$a=array('ftr_file_uploads'=>[['name'=>['Hyd.jpg']],['name'=>['w.jpg']] ]);
$arr = array();
foreach($a['ftr_file_uploads'] as $files){
   $arr['file_upload']['name'][]=$files['name'][0];
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I have simplified the array.I have many keys in the inner array other than name. I have keys having named type,size,tmp_name,error.How can I get the result

Comment: Try adding this solution in your actual array and check if its working or not

Comment: I  have tried foreach($_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'] as $key=>$files){$newarray['ftr_file_uploads'][$key][]=$files[$key][0];  },Not working

Comment: I have edited the question again.Please can you check

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following to obtain the result

```
foreach($_FILES['ftr_file_uploads'] as $key=>$files){ 
           foreach(array_keys($files) as $k=>$v)
           {
              $newarray['ftr_file_uploads'][$v][]=$files[$v][0];  
           }  
       }
```